# Como fazer integração com o PagSeguro usando UIWebView em Swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview

Estou tentando fazer a integração do PagSeguro com minha aplicação em Swift utilizando UIWebView, utilizando método POST, mas não deu certo. segue erro que está sendo retornado e a parte do meu código onde faço a chamada:

error   NSError domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840   0x79741210

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/")

    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)

    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let parameters = ["email":"v07072797361924052363@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br ",
        "token":"PUB9DC3C03DD97D4FB4AB1EE70161FE3063",
        "itemId1":"0001",
        "itemDescription1":"Notebook Prata",
        "itemAmount1":"24300.00",
        "itemQuantity1":"1",
        "itemWeight1":"1000"]

    do {

        mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())

        mutableURLRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableURLRequest.addValue("charset=ISO-8859-1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(mutableURLRequest, completionHandler: {

            (data, response, error) in

            guard let responseData = data else {

                print("Error: did not receive data")

                return

            }

            guard error == nil else {

                print("error calling POST on /posts/1")

                print(error)

                return

            }

            let post: NSDictionary

            do {

                post = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: []) as! NSDictionary

            }

            catch {

                print("error parsing response from POST on /posts")

                return

            }

            print("resultado: ")

            print(post)

        })

        task.resume()

    }

    catch {

        print("Error parsing response from POST on /posts")

        return

    }
```

Comment: você ja verificou se o JSON que você está recebendo é válido? Isso acontece geralmente quando o response é um JSONP.